# Bayesian modelling of a variation of dice problem

Tags: bayesian

I'll start with the normal case, finding the probability for each face of a dice:

1. Start with uniform prior - Dirichlet distribution with all alphas 1
2. Roll the dice, and depending on the result, compute the posterior distribution

The variation of the problem that I'm dealing with is:

1. Choose a number randomly, say 2
2. Roll the dice
3. You will only know if the result was 2 or not: true/false. If the dice threw 3, you will get false. If it was 2, you will get true as feedback

An example: I ask for one throw of a dice, and ask if the face was '3'. The dice thrower will throw the dice once, and will only tell me if the face was '3' or not.

How should I model this? I can start with the same uniform prior using Dirichlet distribution (with all alphas 1). I can update the prior if the dice result was true. But I'm unsure as to how to update the prior when the dice result is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For illustration purposes, let's assume the dice has 3 faces named A, B, and C.

Using a Dirichlet Prior with parameters: α<sub>A</sub>, α<sub>B</sub>, α<sub>C</sub>.

Say, the probability of A, B, and C are θ<sub>A</sub>, θ<sub>B</sub> and θ<sub>C</sub>.Then,

- The likelihood of success when asked for face A: θ<sub>A</sub>
- The likelihood of failure when asked for face A: (1 - θ<sub>A</sub>)
- The likelihood of success when asked for face B: θ<sub>B</sub>
- The likelihood of failure when asked for face B: (1 - θ<sub>B</sub>)
- The likelihood of success when asked for face C: θ<sub>C</sub>
- The likelihood of failure when asked for face C: (1 - θ<sub>C</sub>)

Let's indicate the number of successes when asked for face A as N<sub>AS</sub>, and the number of failures when asked for face A as N<sub>AF</sub>. Similar definitions for N<sub>BS</sub>, N<sub>BF</sub>, N<sub>CS</sub>, N<sub>CF</sub>.

Then the net likelihood function is
θ<sub>A</sub><sup>N<sub>AS</sub></sup> * (1 - θ<sub>A</sub>)<sup>N<sub>AF</sub></sup> * θ<sub>B</sub><sup>N<sub>BS</sub></sup> * (1 - θ<sub>B</sub>)<sup>N<sub>BF</sub></sup> * θ<sub>C</sub><sup>N<sub>CS</sub></sup> * (1 - θ<sub>C</sub>)<sup>N<sub>CF</sub></sup>

From Bayes theorem: Posterior ∝ Prior x Likelihood

Therefore, Posterior distribution P(θ<sub>A</sub>, θ<sub>B</sub>, θ<sub>C</sub>) ∝ (θ<sub>A</sub><sup>α<sub>A</sub> - 1</sup> * θ<sub>B</sub><sup>α<sub>B</sub> - 1</sup> * θ<sub>C</sub><sup>α<sub>C</sub> - 1</sup>) * (θ<sub>A</sub><sup>N<sub>AS</sub></sup> * (1 - θ<sub>A</sub>)<sup>N<sub>AF</sub></sup> * θ<sub>B</sub><sup>N<sub>BS</sub></sup> * (1 - θ<sub>B</sub>)<sup>N<sub>BF</sub></sup> * θ<sub>C</sub><sup>N<sub>CS</sub></sup> * (1 - θ<sub>C</sub>)<sup>N<sub>CF</sub></sup>)